# Sympy string to equation

Tags: python, sympy

Im working on a project with sympy. I want to save some equations in a JSON file. They are saved as a string (for example: "R * C * 1.1, ti"). I have tried to convert the string to a equation (with sy.S() and sy.Eq()), but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sy

def solve():

  R = sy.S(2)
  C = sy.S(1)
  ti = sy.S("ti")

  equation = sy.Eq(sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti"))

  solution = sy.solve(equation, manual = 1)
  print(solution)

solve()
```

I get this warning and a empty solution (when i exchange the string with a normal formula, it works):

> Eq(expr) with rhs default to 0 has been deprecated since SymPy 1.5.
> Use Eq(expr, 0) instead. See
> https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16587 for more info.
>
> deprecated_since_version="1.5"
> []

Comment: What do you mean "it doidn't work"? What does the code do? What is the "normal formula" that works for you? Please [edit] your equation to include this information so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

- `sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti")` doesn't look at existing variables, but creates its own variables that happen to have the external names "R", "C" and "ti.
- `sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti")` creates a tuple `(R * C * 1.1, ti)`
- `sy.Eq()` expects two parameters: the left-hand side and the right-hand side of an equation.  Older versions of sympy where also happy with just the left-hand side and imagined the right-hand side to be `0`. This still works, but is strongly discouraged as it won't work any more in future versions.
- With `sy.Eq(sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti"))`, there is only one parameter (a tuple) for `sy.Eq`. So this provokes the deprecated warning.
- To convert a tuple to parameters, Python now uses the [`*` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-a-function-call): `func(*(a,b))` calls `func` with two parameters: `func(a,b)`. On the other hand `func((a,b))` calls `func` with just one parameter, the tuple `(a,b)`.
- To assign values to the variables obtained via `sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti")`, a dictionary that maps strings to values can be used.
- Although `True` and `False` are represented internally as `1` and `0`, it is highly recommended to explicitly use the names. Among others, this helps with readability and maintainability of code.

```py
import sympy as sy

def solve():
    value_dict = {"R": 2, "C": 1}
    equation = sy.Eq(*sy.S("R * C * 1.1, ti")).subs(value_dict)
    solution = sy.solve(equation, manual=True)
    print(solution)

solve()
```

If you need `ti` to be an accessible sympy variable, you can add it to the dictionary:

```py
    ti = sy.symbols("ti")
    value_dict = {"R": 2, "C": 1, "ti": ti}
```

Comment: You're a genius :) Thank you very much, it works now.